# When should we use command line arguments?

Tags: java, command-line, arguments

I found codes getting input as command line arguments.I am using Eclipse but the example code in Algorithms 4th Edition accepts args[0] and so on.I knew we can input argument in Eclipse.
**Edit starts**
In Eclipse,I need to go to the `Run Configuration` in order to enter the argument when there is a line of code like this `int T = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);`
But it's obvious that if we write the code`int T = scanner.nextInt();`
I don't even need to go to `Run Configuration`to enter the `Program Arguments` and all I need is just click the `run` button and input the value in the console of Eclipse.
**Edit ends.**
So,My question is:

> 1)What is the function(s) for using command line arguments when we can solve the problem using Scanner class?

Thanks for any explanations!

Comment: Scanner doesn't read command line arguments.

Comment: Oh maybe I need to show some code. There is a larger scope of knowledge related to command line argument. I have just seen a part of it, I think. Please refer to at the question again, Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is just an another way of doing things. Sometimes command line arguments are useful for quickly checking how your program responds with different inputs. I guess you just started your programming journey and that is why you are asking question like this.

And let me tell you there is a difference between argument and input. Scanner class helps you to take input from the console whereas command line arguments are passed as an argument to your main function.

Here are some advantages of using command line arguments.

1. You can pass any number of arguments and you do not need to define variables for them.
2. The next benefit is you can pass any data type with command line and then you can code your functions accordingly.

And the final answer for you, don't think about why this when we already have this. It is programming and you should learn as much as you can. You will find 1000s ways of doing the same thing. So enjoy learning.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification and advice! There are a lot more things to learn.

Answer (score 1):

When you compile your code, you execute `javac MyClass.java`
When you run the code, you execute `java MyClass`.

Well, `MyClass.java` is a command line argument to the `javac` command, and `MyClass` is a command line argument to the `java` command.

Do you think those commands would be better if they instead stopped and asked for the values they need? Especially considering there are a lot of options that can be set, so should they ask for each option, one at a time, so you'd have to press Enter 20+ times before the compilation started?

That is just 2 examples for command-line arguments, and how useful they can be.

Let's use another example. We want to create a Zip file, which at its simplest need a name for the Zip file, and a list of file names to add to the Zip file.

Using Scanner, that might look like this:

```
java CreateZip
Enter name of Zip file: foo.zip
Enter name of file to include, blank when done: Hello.txt
Enter name of file to include, blank when done: Yeehaa.txt
Enter name of file to include, blank when done: bar.doc
Enter name of file to include, blank when done: baz.png
Enter name of file to include, blank when done:
Zip file created
```

Or you could use command-line arguments:

```
java CreateZip foo.zip Hello.txt Yeehaa.txt bar.doc baz.png
Zip file created
```

Which approach is better? What if you want to do that from a script? How can the script answer questions?

Comment: I found it useful for using command line argument now. Thank you for you detailed explanation!